# Bash: sort text file by last field value

Tags: sorting, sed, awk

I have a text file containing ~300k rows. Each row has a varying number of comma-delimited fields, the last of which is guaranteed numerical. I want to sort the file by this last numerical field. I can't do:

```
sort -t, -n -k 2 file.in > file.out
```

as the number of fields in each row is not constant. I think sed, awk maybe the answer, but not sure how. E.g:

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' file.in
```

gives me the last column value, but how to use this to sort the file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use awk to put the numeric key up front. `$NF` is the last field of the current record. Sort. Use sed to remove the duplicate key.

```
awk -F, '{ print $NF, $0 }' yourfile | sort -n -k1 | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]* //'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
vim file.in -c '%sort n /.*,\zs/' -c 'saveas file.out' -c 'q'
```

Comment: Why not use `ex` if you're going to go that route?  Vim gets that particular functionality from `ex` anyway.

Comment: `ex` is just `vim`, with the `-e` option. Does not really matter in this case.

Comment: `ex` predates `vim` (and `vi`) by quite a long time.  `vim` may have an `ex` emulation mode, but this does not make it `ex`.

Comment: Yes. But if you have vim on your system, `ex` will be a symlink to `vim` usually. Vim detects at startup what name it has been invoked under.

Comment: Wew demon magic, here's another that suits me and sorts all by column 3  `%sort n /^\([0-9.-]\+\s\+\)\{3}\zs[0-9.-]\ze/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reverse the fields of each line in the file before sorting?  Something like

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print(join(",",reverse(split(","))),"\n")' |
  sort -t, -n -k1 |
  perl -ne 'chomp; print(join(",",reverse(split(","))),"\n")'
```

should do it, as long as commas are never quoted in any way.  If this is a full-fledged CSV file (in which commas can be quoted with backslash or space) then you need a real CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner:

```
@lines=<STDIN>;foreach(sort{($a=~/.*,(\d+)/)[0]<=>($b=~/.*,(\d+)/)[0]}@lines){print;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw mine in here as an alternative (and I couldn't get awk to work) :)

sample file:

```
Call of Doody                           1322
Seam the Ripper                         1329
Mafia Bots 1                            1109
Chicken Fingers                         1243
Batup Light                             1221
Hunter F Tomcat                         1140
Tober                                   0833
```

code:

```
for i in `sed -e 's/.* \(\d\)*/\1/' file.txt | sort`; do grep $i file.txt; done > file_sort.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Python one-liner:

```
python -c "print ''.join(sorted(open('filename'), key=lambda l: int(l.split(',')[-1])))"
```