# How to sort groups of lines together?

Tags: unix, sorting, awk

I have this file:

```
rs1    1    ADD     0.7     0.75     0.45
rs1    1    VAR     0.4     4.53     0.06
rs1    1    USER    NA      1.96     0.37
rs2    2    ADD     1.5     0.25     0.23
rs2    2    VAR     0.4     4.86     0.03
rs2    2    USER    NA      1.73     0.05
rs3    3    ADD     0.29    0.76     0.97
rs3    3    VAR     0.44    3.95     0.09
rs3    3    USER    0.96    5.41     0.01
```

For each value in `$1`, there are three lines with `ADD`, `VAR`, `USER` in `$3`. I want to sort (reverse sort) the file based on the `$6` values for lines with `USER` in `$3`. The question is that how I could do this AND at the same time keep the corresponding lines with `ADD`, `VAR` next to the sorted lines. I don't need the other two lines to be sorted; I just need them to be next to the `sorted` line.

Desired output:

```
 rs3    3    ADD     0.29    0.76    0.97
 rs3    3    VAR     0.44    3.95    0.09
 rs3    3    USER    0.96    5.41    0.01
 rs2    2    ADD     1.5     0.25    0.23
 rs2    2    VAR     0.4     4.86    0.03
 rs2    2    USER    NA      1.73    0.05
 rs1    1    ADD     0.7     0.75    0.45
 rs1    1    VAR     0.4     4.53    0.06
 rs1    1    USER    NA      1.96    0.37
```

I have tried this code, but it only sorts based on the `$6` values in `USER` lines:

```
cat File | sort -k1 | uniq | sort -g -k6 > Output
```

Thank you

Comment: +1 for well formated question with sample data, required output, and ... gasp, .... sample code ; -) . You can specify multiple keys to sort. `-k2 -k3 -k6 ` might work. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at this example it is along the same lines I believe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832068/bash-sort-text-file-by-last-field-value

Comment: @shelter: Unfortunately, it does not seem to work

Comment: @TopGunCoder: Actually, my problem is a little different from the one you referred to. That question is interesting though.

Comment: Desired output is not sorted by $6 in any way I can see.

Comment: But... 0.05, 0.01, 0.37 are not sorted, either normal or reverse.

Comment: you might have to think a little bit about *which* multiple keys you want to use. My example doesn't make much sense, and if you sort by col 2 and 3, there's no reason to try and sort  6. Good luck.

Comment: @Phil: Sorry! you are right. Now corrected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit messy but does what you want:

```
paste - - - < File | sort -k18,18g | xargs -n 6
```

The problem with the input format is that sort has no way to operate on groups of input lines, so you need to turn each group into one line, sort it, then turn it back. This only works if the input "USER" line is always last in the group.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner for Ruby :)

```
ruby -e 'File.open(ARGV.shift).readlines.entries.group_by{|e| e.split[1]}.sort.reverse.each{|e| puts e[1]}' file
```

Output:

```
rs3    3    ADD     0.29    0.76     0.97
rs3    3    VAR     0.44    3.95     0.09
rs3    3    USER    0.96    5.41     0.05
rs2    2    ADD     1.5     0.25     0.23
rs2    2    VAR     0.4     4.86     0.03
rs2    2    USER    NA      1.73     0.01
rs1    1    ADD     0.7     0.75     0.45
rs1    1    VAR     0.4     4.53     0.06
rs1    1    USER    NA      1.96     0.37
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to replace the first `File` with my file name as well? Could you explain a little about the code?

Comment: @user2162153 The only thing you need to replace is the argument `file`.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error. I get this error: -e:1: undefined method `group_by' for #<Array:0x2b9c906336e0> (NoMethodError) By the way, I corrected the values in $6 as they were not sorted reversely

Comment: I'll try to explain. The section `File.open(ARGV.shift).readlines.entries` converts all the lines to arrays. `group_by{|e| e.split[1]}` groups data lines into key-value pairs in which the key is the one from the second column, and the value is an array of all the lines that matches it. sort.reverse would sort and reverse those key-value pairs by their keys and converting into a two-element array. And so `each{|e| puts e[1]}` would print every second part of the pair (`e[1]`), which are composed of the lines.

Comment: I use ruby 1.9.3 here. I guess you're using an earlier version?

Comment: You mentioned that `group_by{|e| e.split[1]}` groups data lines into key-value pairs in which the key is the one from the second column`, but what I actually want is to group the lines on the first column. So, I need to replace it with `group_by{|e| e.split[2]}` ?

Comment: @user2162153 `e.split[0]`. But doesn't your ruby not work with `group_by`? Or perhaps you need to update your gems. I don't really know actually. I'm still starting ruby as well.

Comment: Mine is 1.8.5. I work on a cluster, so I am not sure if I have access to install the new version

Comment: According to here. It's in the core, and 1.8.x doesn't have `match_by`. Sorry about that. http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I try to install the new version. Hopefully it works.