# Sort grep matches by the characters' location in character classes

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am trying to use grep to achieve the following:

Given grep patterns like `[mM][aA][rRyY]$`, while `abcMAy`, `defmAy`, `ghimaR` all match the pattern, I would like to sort them by the characters' location in the character class. For example, since `m` appears before `M` in `[mM]`, I want `MAy` to appear last; similarly, since `a` appears before `A` in `[aA]`, I want `maR` to appear before `mAy`.

This is definitely not typical usage, but I'm wondering if it can be done easily?

Comment: I would use `awk` to output the line with the location of the matching character prefixed. Then sort by that column.

Comment: @Barmar Could you show an example of that? I am not very familiar with `awk`.

Comment: Is it always the case that you just want to sort lowercase ahead of uppercase, or is your problem more general than that?

Comment: @Barmar The characters in a class can appear in any arbitrary order.

Comment: I can't think of any easy way to do this. There's no way to get the regexp matcher to return this kind of information. Maybe Perl or PHP would be a better language to write this, because their `sort` functions allow you to supply a user-written comparison function.

Comment: After the regexp tells you that the string matches, you need to step through the matching part of the string. For each character, you need to find its position in the corresponding character class, using a normal string searching function like `strpos()` in PHP.

Comment: If you can build your regex from some more program-friendly source that would help but basically I think you need to do what Barmar suggested and post-process your list. With a custom sort function you could potentially be more clever and apply weights to the individual letters by position and then have the sort function do the heavy lifting but I'm not sure that'd be better.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @Etan! I guess I'm eventually gonna let `grep` display the matching part of the string along with their original line numbers, then use a quick python script to parse the RegEx rule and sort the strings by the indexes of the matching characters.

Comment: OR you can let `awk` find the matching part of the string along with their original line numbers, then use that same awk script to parse the RegEx rule and sort the strings by the indexes of the matching characters. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins but meantime - post some concise, testable, sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Comment: Watching `$` in your regex made me feel that you will need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832068/bash-sort-text-file-by-last-field-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the custom sorting order by decorate/undecorate pattern with awk and sort.  For example

```
$ echo {m,M}{a,A}{r,R,y,Y} | tr ' ' '\n' | 
  awk -v pat='mMaArRyY' '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) 
                            printf "%s", index(pat,substr($0,i,1)); 
                          print "\t" $0}' | 
  sort | cut -f2-

mar
maR
may
maY
mAr
mAR
mAy
mAY
Mar
MaR
May
MaY
MAr
MAR
MAy
MAY
```

**UPDATE**
For overlapping patters [aA][Aa] here is updated solution, to show how the order is determined I didn't include the final cut.

```
$ echo {a,A}{A,a} | tr ' ' '\n' | 
  awk -v pat='aA,Aa' 'BEGIN{n=split(pat,p,",")}
                            {for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++)
                                printf "%s",index(p[i],substr($0,i,1)); 
                             print "\t" $0}' | 
  sort

11      aA
12      aa
21      AA
22      Aa
```

Here is the full script in action

```
$ cat text
abcMay defmaY ghiMark jklMaY443 

$ grep -oE "\S*[mM][aA][rRyY]\S*" text
abcMay
defmaY
ghiMark 
jklMaY443
```

extract the pattern matched sub string

```
$ ... | sed -r 's/(\S*([mM][aA][rRyY])\S*)/\2\t\1/'
May     abcMay
maY     defmaY  
Mar     ghiMark                                    
MaY     jklMaY443

$ ... |  awk -v pat='mM,aA,rRyY' 'BEGIN{n=split(pat,p,",")}
                             {for(i=1;i<=length($1);i++)
                                printf "%s",index(p[i],substr($0,i,1));
                              print "\t" $0}'
  | sort

114     maY     defmaY
211     Mar     ghiMark
213     May     abcMay
214     MaY     jklMaY443
```

everything in order, eliminate dummy keys

```
... | cut -f3-

defmaY
ghiMark
abcMay
jklMaY443
```

Comment: The example inputs in his question are `abcMAy` and `defMay`. Will your solution work for that?

Comment: It looks like your code will match the `a` in `abc` against `pat`, even though it's not part of the regular expression match.

Comment: And what if the pattern is something like `[aA][Aa]`? What would you put in `pat` for that? It needs to sort `aA` ahead of `aa` and `AA`.

Comment: you should extract the matched sub string to solve the first problem.  If the char sequences overlap this solution won't work as is.  However, it can be fixed as well by iterating on pat variable at each match.

Comment: These are the issues that make his question not as simple as your solution suggests.

Comment: @Barmar please see the updated solution for overlapping patterns