# sort text file based on specific filenames

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a bit of a weird problem. I hve a text file which looks like so:

```
/path/to/dir/0/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/0/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/0/102_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/102_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/102_something.dat,0.6
```

and I would like to sort it so that it looks like so:

```
/path/to/dir/0/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/100_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/0/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/101_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/0/102_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/1/102_something.dat,0.6
/path/to/dir/2/102_something.dat,0.6
```

How can I achieve this in bash please? I used to sorting numerically via `sort -n` but I am not sure how to sort the above case since the field seperator and the field are not exactly useful (at least straightaway)

Comment: `sort -t/ -n -k6,6 -k5,5`

Comment: oh can be please explain a bit please? I understand the -t option but what is `-k6,6 -k5,5` I ask because my paths are different (i only provided an example) so I would like to understand please

Comment: will all filenames start with 3 digits, or could the number of digits vary? likewise, will the lowest level directory always be a single digit, or could the number of digits here also vary?

Comment: `-k` option is described in manpage or [posix spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)

Comment: @jhnc I got it now :) could you please post it as an answer please and I will accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of path elements is constant and each line has the same number of them, then `sort` alone can do this.

In your example, each line contains 6 path elements delimited by `/` (lines start with an empty element).

You seem to want to sort by element 6 and then sub-sort on element 5, both numerically.

So:

```
sort -t/ -n -k6,6 -k5,5 inputfile
```

The `-k` can take more options. See manpage for details.

---

If the number of path elements is not constant, you may need a different solution. For example: [Bash: sort text file by last field value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3832068/10971581)